# PathParam with Jersey REST

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm developing a REST web service in which I use a ID in the URL to specify a patient, like this:

> `WS/services/patient/1`

Where "1" is the id of the patient. So, in the code, I specified like this:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public void getPatient(@PathParam("id") int cId) {
...
}
```

I saw it in one example, but mine is failing. I'm getting this error:

> *com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Method, public void PresentationLayer.PatientResource.getPatient(int), annotated with GET of resource, class PresentationLayer.PatientResource, is not recognized as valid Java method annotated with @HttpMethod.*

I don't know why is doing this. In the example I saw it worked. Any hints?

EDIT: If I dont write the @PathParams("id"), it works... but then, how can I get the id from the url?

Comment: As a guess: you need to return some content, but your return type is *void*.

Comment: Turn up your logging level to DEBUG or ALL. In cases like this, when resolving configuration issues, you need to be able to see exactly what is going on under the hood. Feel free to [edit] your question further to include more details as you learn more about the problem. As it stands currently, I'm not sure this is answerable yet, but it's a good start and with more details it could be a great question. Good luck!

Comment: Why I need to return anything? If I dont write the @PathParams in the parameters site, it works well (but then I cant get the id from the url...)

Comment: @Frion3L: What's the purpose of your `GET` if not to retrieve something?

Comment: @Greg Kopff yeah, you are right! It was it... So many time wasted searching the error... Really thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Method, **public *void* PresentationLayer.PatientResource.getPatient(int)**, annotated with GET of resource, class PresentationLayer.PatientResource, is not recognized as valid Java method annotated with @HttpMethod.

You are trying to service a `GET` request using a method that returns no response (return type `void`).